# MySQL DISTINCT for not all columns

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FRUITS (
  ID INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  owner VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  fruit VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  colour VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  comments VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  incident_date DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
INSERT INTO `your_db`.`FRUITS` (ID, owner, fruit, colour, comments, incident_date) VALUES 
  (NULL, 'Sam', 'apple', 'green', 'bought', '2016-11-01'),
  (NULL, 'John', 'lemon', 'yellow', 'borrowed', '2016-11-02'),
  (NULL, 'Oscar', 'lemon', 'yellow', 'found', '2016-11-03'),
  (NULL, 'Oscar', 'apple', 'green', 'stolen', '2016-11-04'),
  (NULL, 'Sam', 'kiwi', 'green', 'inherited', '2016-11-05'),
  (NULL, 'Oscar', 'apple', 'green', 'eaten', '2016-11-06'),
  (NULL, 'Oscar', 'apple', 'yellow', 'grown', '2016-11-09');
```

I have a Datatable with people and their possessions that gets its data from MySQL query, and I need to filter out the apples that Oscar has handled. I don't care if they were found, stolen or eaten, but I need to get the last incident (that it was eaten on November 6th). Basically, only 2 rows:

```
Oscar | apple | green  | eaten | 2016-11-06
Oscar | apple | yellow | grown | 2016-11-09
```

This one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM FRUITS 
  WHERE owner LIKE 'Osc%' AND fruit LIKE 'apple' AND colour LIKE '%%'
  ORDER BY owner ASC
```

returns 3 rows (green ones both stolen and eaten), but I need only the latter.

It would be nice to have a possibility to separate Distinct columns like this:

```
SELECT comments, incident_date, DISTINCT owner, fruit, colour 
  FROM FRUITS WHERE owner LIKE 'Osc%' AND fruit LIKE 'apple' AND colour LIKE '%%' 
  ORDER BY owner ASC
```

This possibility doesn't exist. Is there any others?

(Real case scenario is that advertisement proposals in a magazine are made to customers. Some proposals are made at different times to same area (ex. 1/2 page) at different times. I only need to filter out that a proposal to this customer for this ad size is rejected at that date. Two different rejections are confusing.)

Comment: If you think about it, the concept of a "partial distinct" doesn't even really make sense. Try `ORDER BY incident_date DESC, ID DESC LIMIT 1` instead.

Comment: True enough, partial Distinct is probably a bad idea. Your suggestion would work, but I clarified the question a bit so it doesn't work anymore :) I've seen answers for SQL Server that use PARTITION, but in this case?

Comment: You tagged "greatest-n-per-group". Did you not have any luck finding an answer elsewhere? This is a common one.

Comment: @shawnt00 I added that tag. It is a common question. I actually created that tag years ago, and there are now thousands of questions tagged with it!

Comment: @Konservin, MySQL doesn't support windowing functions yet.

Comment: Sorry, I had no idea of "greatest-n-per-group" tag

Comment: @BillKarwin I looked at the edit history before posting the comment but apparently I read it wrong. My mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variation of the very common [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) question.

How can you get a row that is the most recent row for a given combination of owner/fruit/colour?

In other words, try to join such a row (call it F1) to another row (call it F2) with the same owner/fruit/colour, and a more recent id. If no match is found, the outer join will return all NULLs for `F2.*`.

```
SELECT F1.* FROM FRUITS AS F1
LEFT OUTER JOIN FRUITS AS F2
  ON F1.owner = F2.owner
  AND F1.fruit = F2.fruit
  AND F1.colour = F2.colour
  AND F1.ID < F2.ID
WHERE F2.ID IS NULL AND F1.owner = 'Oscar' AND F1.fruit = 'apple';
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to generate a set of data w/o comments for each unique owner, fruit color and max incident date, then join back to base set to include the comment.

```
SELECT * 
FROM fruits F
INNER JOIN (SELECT max(Incident_date) mID, Owner, Fruit, Color
            FROM Fruits
            GROUP BY Owner, Fruit, Color) FM
 on FM.Owner = F.Owner
and Fm.Fruit = F.Fruit
and FM.Color = F.Color
and FM.Mid = F.Incident_Date
WHERE F.Owner = 'Oscar' and F.Fruit = 'apple'
```

If you don't care about which comment the engine selects, a simple group by in mySQL would work...
mySQL extends the group by so the comment picked by the engine will be indeterminate since it's not in the group by.

```
SELECT Owner, Fruit, Color, comment, max(Incident_date)
FROM Fruit
GROUP BY Owner, Fruit, Color
```

Comment: +1 This solution works too. Different solutions perform better over different databases, depending on how many matches per group, and other factors. It's a good idea to test both solutions against the data you're going to use it for, to see which works better. And create correct indexes first.